# How should I optimize my MySQL Query or Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database-table with about 33 million rows. I'm trying to optimize my queries. Right now I'm only using a smaller version of the dataset with 8 million rows. If I run this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_size FROM data WHERE c_name = 'jeans'
```

It will return the data in 176 seconds
If I run:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT c_size FROM data WHERE c_name = 'jeans'
```

This is the result.

```
id: 1   
select_type : SIMPLE
table : data
type : index
possible_keys : NULL    
key : c_size
key_len : 5
ref : NULL
rows :  14876049
Extra : Using where
```

Do you have any pointers to how I could optimize my queries, my table or my database? The database is running through MAMP. I'm administrating the database with Sequel Pro.

Comment: Is there an index on c_name ?

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: @JacodeGroot Oh, look at that.. I missed that. What size would you suggest for the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following index on the data table might help performance:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_data_c_name ON data (c_name);
```

Comment: That did bring the query time down to 4 seconds. That is still quite a bit of time though. Or is that normal?

Comment: Do you already have a clustered index on the table ? If not you could change this index to a clustered one and that would speed up your results

Comment: What is a clustered index? Is that when I add several (all?) columns to the same index?

Comment: Every InnoDB table has a special index called the clustered index where the data for the rows is stored. Accessing a row through the clustered index is fast because the index search leads directly to the page with all the row data. Typically, the clustered index is synonymous with the primary key, but you can also add it on other (multiple columns). Is the c_name column unique or can you make it unique by adding another column ?